# Where are html files stored in plugins of wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

Where are html files stored in plugins of wordpress? I need to edit the html and CSS files of a plugin. But I can't find the html file. Please let me know where they are stored.

Comment: Probably as PHP files inside the plugin directory

Comment: No, there are only php files, no html files.

Comment: Can you give us the plugin download link ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. PHP gets converted to HTML

Answer (score 0):

wp-content/plugins/thenameofplugins/index.php

There is not HTML files, only PHP. But you can find CSS

Comment: I can't find the CSS file. Actually there is no css file in this plugin. How do I edit the CSS?

Comment: if there is no CSS you can add one through Filezila and link it in the header.php with something like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">

or edit the CSS of the theme

Comment: Another question::

I have to edit a wordpress website. There's a page named Shop. When I open the page, there is not text in it. But wooCommerce plugin is installed in it.

I want to know, how without mentioning anywhere, Shop page is linked to WooCommerce plugin?

Sorry, I know the question sounds dumb. But I am new to Wordpress.

Comment: In your woocommerce file into the famous plugin file, you can find a template file where there is your shop page.
Woocommerce automatically add some page like shop or card or account.